# Examples of open source production level DApps on Cardano?

Tags: plutus, decentralized-applications

I am looking for Cardano DApps which are:

1. Actually deployed and used on mainnet
2. Have published their source code (at least on-chain part)

Examples of non-Plutus PL used (like Plutarch, Aiken, ...) are especially important to me.

I am interested in non Open Source projects as well, but I think it would make question too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Plutarch team provided two examples for me:

- https://github.com/Liqwid-Labs/agora/
- https://github.com/mlabs-haskell/cardano-open-oracle-protocol